# PSQL Exception on column length

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, lob

I get an `internal exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Error value too long for varying character (255)` when i try to insert using EclipseLink JPA a value for a description on a certain entity. I thought using the `@LOB` annotation and setting a max length on the column would take care of it as follows:

```
@Size(min = 0, max = 9000)
@Lob
@Column(name = "description", length = 2000)
private String description;
```

but this does not solve the problem, how can i specify that i want a non binding length for this column as it could be very large

Comment: Use a `text` column instead of `varchar(255)`. Actually, you should forget about `varchar` with PostgreSQL and always use `text` (unless of course there is a real length constraint).

Comment: i am using the Java persistence api, how does the type text convert into that api, i am looking for the annotation that translates to that

Comment: I don't know JPA, that's why I'm just commenting to point you in the right direction.

Comment: There's no limit to varchar in PostgreSQL. You can use varchar() to store strings of any size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that i have to recreate all the tables for this effect to work `@Lob` declares the text type in postgresql.